# Cannot store full labels of my Seaborn (heatmap) plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a problem storing labels in my Seaborn heatmap. The labels I have are pretty long. When I use `plt.show()` to show my plots, I can see the full labels by resizing the canvas. However, when I save to a file, only a small fraction of the label is stored. I used the following code in Seaborn `0.7.1`:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(some_matrix)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels=some_labels,rotation=0)
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig("my_file.png",dpi=600)
```

Any clue how I can increase the size of the canvas such that the full labels are stored in my `.png` file? Reducing the font size may not be a nice solution, since there are a lot of labels on the Y axis, resulting in labels becoming unreadable.

Comment: There are several ways to help with this problem, but without seeing your code or an example of your figure, its hard to say which would be most suitable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig):

> bbox_inches:
>   Bbox in inches. Only the given portion of the figure is
>   saved. If ‘tight’, try to figure out the tight bbox of the figure.

```
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], 'o-')
plt.yticks([1, 2, 3], ['a really really long label']*3)
plt.savefig('test1.png')
```

[image: test1]

```
plt.savefig('test2.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: test2]

Comment: That was actually easier than I expected, thanks a lot!